# DIV no carga en su contenido página PHP completa

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

tengo una página php con contenido html y un div, dependiendo del valor que selecciono desde un combobox, llamo a una página php y la cargo completa en el div, si la cargo sin pasar parámetros en su url se carga, pero con una grilla vacía ya que no puede completarla porque necesita leer el parámetro pasado, si la paso con parámetros en la url, directamente no lo carga en el div, no hace nada, probé redireccionando la web sin parámetros y me muestra la página con su grilla vacía, si le paso parámetros, no redirecciona, parece ser que los parámetros son un problema

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Prueba</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="wb_div_database">
      <div id="div_database">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1">
               <select name="cbx_datadases" size="1" id="cbx_datadases"  style="display:block;width:100%;height:28px;z-index:0;" title="Seleccionar base de datos">

               <?php
                  $enlace = mysql_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'clave');
                  $resultado = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
                  while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) 
                  {
                    echo'<OPTION VALUE="'.$fila['Database'].'">'.$fila['Database'].'</OPTION>';
                  }
               ?> 
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="wb_div_tablas" style="display:none;">
      <div id="div_tablas">
         <div class="row">
            <div id="tablas" class="col-1">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

<script>
$("#cbx_datadases").change(function () { 

    var nombreBaseDatos=this.value ;

         opción 1 - $("#tablas").load("showtables.php?basedatos="+this.value); 

         opción 2 - $("#tablas").load("showtables.php",{basedatos:this.value}, function(response, status, xhr)
                    {
                                   if (status == "error") 
                       {
                                      var msg = "Error!, algo ha sucedido: ";
                                      $("#tablas").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                       }
                            };

        opción 3 - $("#tablas").load('showtables.php?basedatos='+nombreBaseDatos);
        //$("#wb_div_tablas").fadeIn(800);

        opción 4 - window.locationf='showtables.php?basedatos='+this.value;
        opción 5 - window.location.href = 'showtables.php';   


}); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ya probé de copiar la URL generada desde mi código, la pego en una nueva pestaña y funciona perfecto, por lo cual, la web que quiero mostrar en el DIV funciona perfectamente.
No sé dónde está el problema, probé con Get() en vez de load() y me pasa lo mismo.

**AGREGO :**

Si hago :

```
<div id="tablas" class="col-1"> 
    <?php include("showtables.php"); ?>
</div>
```

me muestra el contenido de la página showtables.php perfecto, pero con la grilla vacía porque no paso parámetros, en cambio si paso parámetros, hasta con harcode,

```
<div id="tablas" class="col-1"> 
    <?php include("showtables.php?basedatos=baseprueba"); ?>
</div>
```

no muestra nada, de hecho, como si `$("#wb_div_tablas").fadeIn(800);` no funcionara

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta para agregar el código de `showtables.php`

Comment: Hola @Triby, gracias por tu colaboración, no creí necesario copiar el código del archivo showtables.php ya que este funciona perfectamente, lo llamo en otra pestaña del navegador copiando la ur que genera el index.php y funciona perfecto, el problema es que, como dije antes, parece que el problema es cuando le agrego los parámetros en la URL, además de lño extensísimo del archivo showtables.php.Gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que estás usando jQuery para manejar el evento, en vez de usar

```
this.value
```

intenta con:

```
$(this).val()
```